# Why can I not assign a Name value to UserControls that are scoped as Internal in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl, which I have set to Internal as such:

```
UserControl x:Class="ClassName"
             x:ClassModifier="internal"
```

And it's matching .cs file:

```
 internal partial class ClassName : UserControl
    {
        public ClassName()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Now, when I try to use the control on a window, like this:

```
 uControls:ClassName x:Name="instanceName" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseLeftButtonUp="instanceName_MouseLeftButtonUp" Cursor="ScrollNW"
```

I get an error stating:

```
The type 'ClassName' cannot have a Name attribute. Value types and types without a default constructor can be used as items within a ResourceDictionary. Line 12 Position 44.
```

If I change the access modifiers to public, all works as expected.

Why can I not have internal User Controls?

Comment: Is your window in the same assembly as your control?

Comment: Yes.  I'm only working with one assembly, though they are in different namespaces.  The namespace is included at the top of the Window's xaml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is caused by the compilation model for WPF.  I'm quoting this from memory and can't find a resource to back it up, but I believe that WPF compilation happens in two passes: essentially the "codebehind" portion is compiled first to an intermediate assembly, then the XAML is compiled as referencing that intermediate, and the results are combined to the final assembly.

For this reason, the classes/members that the XAML references have to be declared publicly, because (as far as the compiler is concerned) they're in a separate assembly to the XAML.

**EDIT:** found a Microsoft reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970678.aspx) that outlines the process.  In particular, in terms of supporting what I said above, it says:

> if one or more XAML files in the project have references to locally defined types, then a temporary .dll file is generated so the final application assemblies may be created after the second pass of markup compilation is complete.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It seems like a really bizarre way of doing things.  Typical M$.

Answer (score 2):

I know, e.g., that resources used in XAML must be public even if in the same assembly. I believe that's because he is using reflection and only takes into account public stuff but i'm guessing a little bit about the internal implementation.

I know i had other issues with public/internal access modifiers but i can't remember now.

You might be experience the same restriction regarding the UserControl Name Property.

Overall, regarding my limited experience in WPF, it's a very powerful framework but, unfortunately, you have to 'forget' some good practices along the way.

For example, Dependency Properties are cumbersome to specify. I always felt that a DependencyProperty keyword was missing to abstract me from all that.